# Adding DataRow object to DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm trying to loop through my database looking for specific rows with date ranges.
Whenever I try to use DataTable.Import(DataRow) it adds a new row with no values inside.
How do I "import" a DataRow into a DataTable?
Here is the loop, thanks!

```
        public DataTable FilterDataTableByDates(DataTable td, DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        DataTable tempTd = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataRow dr in td.Rows)
        {
            long ticks = Convert.ToInt64(dr["cpd_date"].ToString());
            if (ticks > from.Ticks && ticks < to.Ticks)
            {
                tempTd.ImportRow(dr);
            }
        }
        return tempTd.Copy();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Add method to copy a DataRow from one datatable to another :

```
tempTd.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
```

Even your method could work but you have to create your DataTable coping the structure from the origin :

```
DataTable tempTd = td.Clone();
```

With the [Clone()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx) method you create a new datatable with the same structure of the original datatable, then you can import row in it.

So your complete method will become :

```
public DataTable FilterDataTableByDates(DataTable td, DateTime from, DateTime to)
{
    DataTable tempTd = td.Clone();
    foreach (DataRow dr in td.Rows)
    {
        long ticks = Convert.ToInt64(dr["cpd_date"].ToString());
        if (ticks > from.Ticks && ticks < to.Ticks)
        {
            tempTd.ImportRow(dr);
        }
    }
    return tempTd.Copy();
}
```